# how do I let users input a dynamic 2D array?

Tags: c

```
int main(){
int limit_x;
int limit_y;
scanf("%d", &limit_x);
scanf("%d", &limit_y);
char map[limit_x][limit_y];
    for (int index_x=0;index_x<limit_x;index_x++)
    {
        for (int index_y = 0; index_y < limit_y; index_y++)
        {
            scanf("%c", &map[index_x][index_y]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I try to do it , but it is not working for me .
it shows error C2057,C2466.

Let users input the row and col, and make a dynamic 2d array map by input.

Comment: `char map[x][y];` is a variable length array which some compilers, Microsoft's in particular, do not support. You need to use dynamic allocations (e.g.: `malloc`) instead

Comment: @hu xiuleiwe Show error messages.

Comment: 'identifier' : unknown size,'identifier' : missing subscript,cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 @VladfromMoscow

Comment: microsoft compilers do not support VLAs - thus the error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not expect anyone to know error numbers of a specific compiler you do not even mention. Instead simply copy&paste the exact and complete error message into the question.

Comment: @hu xiuleiwe, Please  post exact example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft compiler does not support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). The [ISO C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) standard also does not require that compilers support them, because since ISO C11, it is an optional feature.

If you want to have equivalent functionality as variable-length arrays with a Microsoft Compiler, you have these two options:

- Use [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) instead. However, this will also require you to use [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) when you no longer need the memory, otherwise you will have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).
- Use the platform-specific function [`_alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170), which will cause the memory to automatically be freed when the calling function returns.

However, both of these solutions do not allow you to create an actual 2D array, only a 1D array. Therefore, you will have to calculate the offsets manually to "simulate" a 2D array. Here is an example which uses `_alloca`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int limit_x;
    int limit_y;
    char *map;

    scanf("%d", &limit_x);
    scanf("%d", &limit_y);

    //discard newline character
    getchar();

    //allocate map as a 1D array
    map = _alloca( limit_x * limit_y );

    for ( int index_x=0; index_x < limit_x; index_x++ )
    {
        for ( int index_y = 0; index_y < limit_y; index_y++ )
        {
            //simulate a 2D array by calculating the offsets into
            //the 1D array manually
            scanf("%c", &map[index_x*limit_y+index_y]);
        }
    }

    //print the array for testing purposes
    for ( int index_x=0; index_x < limit_x; index_x++ )
    {
        printf(
            "Characters in outer array element #%d: %.*s\n",
            index_x, limit_y, map+index_x*limit_y
        );
    }
}
```

For the input

```
4
5
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJ
```

this program has the following output:

```
Characters in outer array element #0: 01234
Characters in outer array element #1: 56789
Characters in outer array element #2: ABCDE
Characters in outer array element #3: FGHIJ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
int y;
scanf("%d", &x);
scanf("%d", &y);
char** map = malloc(sizeof(char*) * x);
for (int index=0; index < x; index++)
{
    map[index] = malloc(sizeof(char) * y);
}
for (int index_x=0;index_x<x;index_x++)
{
    for (int index_y = 0; index_y < y; index_y++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &map[index_x][index_y]);
    }
}
```

now is working for me thx alot @UnholySheep;

Comment: This isn't a 2D array however.

Comment: If you call `malloc`, you should also call `free` when you no longer need the memory.

Answer (score 1):

> it shows error C2057,C2466.

It appears to be warnings  "C2057 expected constant expression" and "C2466 cannot allocate an array of constant size 0". That's nonsense. The C compiler should *not* expect a constant expression and there is no array of size zero.

You get these warnings because your compiler is non-conforming to the C language. Please ensure that you compiled as C and not C++. If you still have problems, you should switch to a compiler from year 1999 or later. I recommend using gcc.

(Note: compilers conforming to C11 or C17 may declare `__STDC_NO_VLA__` and then they may claim to be compliant, given that they declared `__STDC__` in the first place. This is not the case for Microsoft Visual C.)

Comment: im using the VS and there is not have a spefic C compiler on it , so i modify C++ version one and using it. Any suggetion for looking a new compiler for C？

Comment: @huxiuleiwe The C compiler should be called cl.exe. I'm not using Visual Studio since forever, but I think it nowadays also supports picking gcc/mingw which is a conforming C compiler. You'd have to ask someone familiar with the IDE. Otherwise you can just download something like Codeblocks and get gcc pre-installed.